# How to create a debug file for an imported project in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I want to use Eclipse to debug a C project that I created using a different IDE (Sublime Text). I already imported the project into Eclipse along with its makefile.

```
TARGET = $(BIN_DIR)/sim_tcp_ip
LIBS = -lpthread -L ./CommandParser -lcli -lrt
OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/prueba.o \
       $(OBJ_DIR)/ListaEnlazada.o \
       $(OBJ_DIR)/Grafico.o \
       $(OBJ_DIR)/Net.o \
       $(OBJ_DIR)/Topologias.o \
       $(OBJ_DIR)/Com.o
BIN_DIR = ./bin
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
INC_DIR = ./inc
SRC_DIR = ./src
CFLAGS = -lpthread -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) CommandParser/libcli.a
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET) $(LIBS)
    
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    gcc -c -MD $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    
CommandParser/libcli.a:
    (cd CommandParser; make)

-include $(OBJ_DIR)/*.d
    
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
    (cd CommandParser; make clean)
all:
    make
    (cd CommandParser; make)
```

The problem is that when I select the debug option, Eclipse asks for a file to debug, and the executable that is created by my makefile can't be used for debugging.

What should I add to my makefile so that it generates a debug file that can work with Eclipse?

Comment: Did you try to add the option "-g" to the compile and link flags? GCC needs this to generate debugging symbols.

Comment: @thebusybee It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the option "-g" to the flags for compiling and linking. This adds debugging symbols to the application.